# how to send e-mail in view of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendmail

i have a web, when the web have a Certain conditions let say if($status == "accept") then the web will be load the code on the bellow of this question, so the code will be load on the page, when the condition like that i want to send email, i try to code like on the bellow but it doesn't work.

```html
  <?php
 
 if($keterangan != 'id_card' && $userId == $userData['id']){
           
            $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 587,
            'smtp_user' => 'example@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'example'
          );
        
         $nama = $userData['nama_lengkap'];
   $email = $userData['email'];

          $this->load->library('email',$config);
          $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

          $this->email->from('example@gmail.com', 'blabla');
          $this->email->to($email);
          $this->email->subject('bla bla bla');
          $this->email->message('hello');
                
                if($this->email->send()){;
                       redirect('dashboard','refresh');
              }else{
                $this->session->set_userdata('id_tmp',$id2);
                       redirect('view_pengumuman','refresh');
              }
                
            }
 ?>
```

edited

```html
           require_once('./asset/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('./asset/phpmailer/class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$message = "hello";
$subject = "hello";

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port
$mail->Username   = "xxxxxxxo@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

$mail->SetFrom( 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'COMPANY' );
$mail->AddAddress( 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'some people' );
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$sendEmail = $mail->Send();
        
                
    if( $sendEmail == true )
{
    redirect('view_pengumuman','refresh');
}
else
{
    redirect('dashboard','refresh');
}

            }
?>
```

Comment: @AbdullaNilam yeah, the issue is just with mail sending

Comment: @AbdullaNilam can i sending mail from view of codeigniter?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam can you give me an example